# Accessing MuleMessage and a flow variable from Java component

Tags: java, mule

I have a Java component that receives a payload (JsonData), like this:

```
public String myMethod(JsonData payload) throws IOException {
  // do things with payload.
}
```

This is working fine, but I also need to access a flow variable within the method. I understand that, to do so, I need to run myMessage.getInvocationProperty("my-variable-name");
However, since I'm only passing the payload, I don't have access to the MuleMessage. How can I change my method so I can get access to my message/property?

I tried:

```
org.mule.RequestContext.getEvent().getMessage()
```

but it is deprecated.

Also, I've read all sorts of answers on this issue but never found a complete answer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the flow variable as a second argument to `myMethod` via the `invoke` message processor.

So, assuming the new signature of `myMethod` is:

```
public String myMethod(JsonData payload, String myVariable) throws IOException {
  // do things with payload.
}
```

you would do:

```
<invoke object-ref="myComponent"
        method="myMethod"
        methodArguments="#[message.payload],#[flowVars['my-variable-name']]" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, but this is not a complete solution, yet. I have very little experience with either Java or Mule, and so I'm still a little puzzled by what you mean with 'via the invoke' message processor. What would it look like concretely?

Comment: For sure, I've extended my answer.

Comment: @DavidDossot Hi, David. What I need within Java component is the whole MuleMesage(Want to enrich it in Java). I tried pass #[message], but got error 'Could not find a transformer to transform \"SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.el.context.MessageContext, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}\" to \"SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.MuleMessage, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}\"

Also, with annotations @Expr(expression="#[message]"), seems it is trying to cast result to String, so doesn't work either.

Comment: Same here. I am trying to pass #[message] as method argument. I get the same exception

Comment: @DavidDossot I have created a java object using the new component and I am trying to pass it in the java function. Can you please look into this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558707/how-to-pass-java-object-to-a-java-function-in-mule   Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 0):

Use the `message.getInvocationProperty` method.

Setting variable:

```
<set-variable variableName="lastname" value="#[payload.lastname]" />
```

Retrieve variable from invocation scope:

```
String lastname = message.getInvocationProperty("lastname");
```