# How do I pass a parameter to a Java Component from a Mule flow?

Tags: java, mule, mule-el, mule-component

I'm just getting started with mule and cant figure out how I can possibly pass a part of my request header as a parameter/argument to the Java component.

My Java Component is as follows

```
public String processHeader(String in)
{
   //process header
   System.out.print(" Header" + in);
}
```

Ive been able to access `processHeader` in the following manner from the flow

```
            <component> 
              <method-entry-point-resolver> 
              <include-entry-point method="processHeader" /> 
              </method-entry-point-resolver> 
              <singleton-object class="my.test.mule.Processor" /> 
            </component>
```

Accessing the above using `http://localhost:8080/test` . Prints `Header test`

I'm able to dump the contents of the header using the following

`<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[headers:INBOUND:*]"/>`

But I cant seem to figure out how to pass the `message` as an argument to `processHeader` nor can I find any relevant examples. Any help would be appreciated.

Btw, I'm using `Mule 3.5` if that matters.

Comment: Which version of Mule are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

implement Callable interface for your java component. When default methods are overridden, you will get eventContext as parameter inside which you can find mule message which in turn gives you access to headers and payload. sample is here:

```
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope;
public class Test implements Callable {

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("header1", PropertyScope.INBOUND);
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: This onCall gets invoked automatically. No explicit call is required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841424/accessing-mulemessage-and-a-flow-variable-from-java-component?rq=1  this answer looks better

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options:

> [@Mule Annotation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Annotation)
>
> A parameter injection annotation that can be used on component entry
>   points and transformer methods, this annotation can be used to execute
>   a Mule Expression on the message payload with the result being passed
>   into the method.

Also:

> [@InboundHeaders Annotation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Payload+Annotation)
>
> This annotation controls how the current message inbound headers are
>   passed into a method. The annotation supports, Map, List, single
>   headers, wildcards and optional entries. It can be used on component
>   entry points and @Transformer methods.

Probably used in conjunction with:

> [@Payload Annotation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Payload+Annotation)
>
> A parameter injection annotation that can be used on component entry
>   points and transformer methods defined using the @Transformer
>   annotation, this annotation controls how the current message payload
>   is passed into a method by performing automatic transformation of the
>   message payload to match the annotated parameter type. For example, if
>   you are expecting an XML document, this can be injected into a
>   component entry point and automatically converted into a
>   org.wc3.dom.Document.

You could also implement Callable as stated in a different response, but that would be much less expressive than this solution.